# How to intercept the response in angular 4 with HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I do have the following Interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      });

      return next.handle(authReq);
    }

    return next
      .handle(req)
//
      .getSomehowTheResponse()
      .andSaveTheTokenInStorage()
      .andPropagateNextTheResponse()
  }
}
```

And I want to save the token from the response header in local storage, all the tutorials are showing how to intercept the request, but not very clearly the response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`next.handle(req)` returns an observable so you can subscribe to it:

```typescript
return next.handle(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    // do stuff with response and headers you want
    event.headers
    event.body
  }
  return event;
})
```

To learn more about mechanics behind interceptors read:

- [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf)

Comment: I got an ts error `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.`

Comment: It is in typescript not compiling.

Comment: I understand, what line?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru: 
Add `return event;` after the if statement block.

Comment: Straight and sweet. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you also need to import library

```
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

then you use as below. you also need to return the event object so that it can be received in your subscribe() function.

```
    return next.handle(req).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response and headers you want
      }
      return event; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Step 1: Import this:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from 
"@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Step 2: In case you are using compact rxjs you can replace 'tap' with 'do'

```
export class RoleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
            return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(
                event=>{
                    console.log('Intercepted! response',event);
                }
            ))    
    }
}
```